# Getting exception while launching yarn jobs due to kafka log4jappender

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j, hadoop-yarn, slf4j

When I run my yarn jobs with this log4j.properties as a configuration it fails with the below exception. If I remove KAFKA from *rootLogger* the jobs launch fine.

This is the same issue that has been reported here:
https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2786

But I have not found a solution for this.

Environment: CDH 6.3.3

This is my log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout,KAFKA
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %L %X{taskId} %X{stsId}     %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}     %c     %t     %m%n  

log4j.appender.alog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.alog.maxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.alog.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.alog.file=../logs/serverx.log
log4j.appender.alog.append=false
log4j.appender.alog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.alog.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p %X{taskId} 
%X{stsId}  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}     %c     %t     %m%n
log4j.appender.KAFKA=org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.conversionPattern=%d%C{1}%t%5p %-4p%X{taskId} %X{stsId} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c %t %m%n%throwable

log4j.appender.KAFKA.topic=cdhuser_rocplus_roclog
log4j.appender.KAFKA.securityProtocol=PLAINTEXT
log4j.appender.KAFKA.ignoreExceptions=false
```

Exception:

```
Unexpected problem occured during version sanity check
Reported exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.versionSanityCheck(LoggerFactory.java:267)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:126)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigs.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<clinit>(ProducerConfig.java:333)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:299)
    at org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender.getKafkaProducer(KafkaLog4jAppender.java:279)
    at org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender.activateOptions(KafkaLog4jAppender.java:273)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$.org$apache$spark$internal$Logging$$isLog4j12(Logging.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.initializeLogIfNecessary(ApplicationMaster.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.initializeLogIfNecessary(ApplicationMaster.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.log(ApplicationMaster.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:786)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<clinit>(ProducerConfig.java:333)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:299)
    at org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender.getKafkaProducer(KafkaLog4jAppender.java:279)
    at org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender.activateOptions(KafkaLog4jAppender.java:273)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$.org$apache$spark$internal$Logging$$isLog4j12(Logging.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.initializeLogIfNecessary(ApplicationMaster.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.initializeLogIfNecessary(ApplicationMaster.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.log(ApplicationMaster.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:786)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:418)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs.<clinit>(CommonClientConfigs.java:32)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: We are facing similar issue on cdh 6.3.3. Can anybody help with some solution?

Comment: Found a workaround. In log4j.properties I am pushing it to rsyslog. Using logstash to read from rsyslog and push to kafka. It seems the solution to this might be available in their next release we have to wait until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem with CDH 6.3.3

Looks like there are a problem with the libraries kafka-log4j-appender:2.2.1-cdh6.3.3 and slf4j-api:1.7.25.

The workarround that used was specify a different version of slf4j-api and  slf4j-log4j12 libraries (Didn't work with 1.7 version and we had to use the 1.8 version).

The steps to solve this issue are:

- First you have to specify these libraries as dependency in the pom.xml file ...

  1.8.0-beta4

  ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  ```
- Use a plugin to copy this dependencies to `target` directory ...

  ```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                    <includeArtifactIds>slf4j-api,slf4j-log4j12</includeArtifactIds>
                    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
  ```
- Include the following properties with spark:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath=slf4j-api.jar:slf4j-log4j12.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath=slf4j-api.jar:slf4j-log4j12.jar
```

- And finally use this parameter with `spark-submit`:

```
--jars slf4j-api.jar,slf4j-log4j12.jar
```